# Adobe AIR failing to load PDF on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

For some reason my app is now returning

> "Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. `Operation not permitted`"

When loading PDFs

```
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(true);
var url:String = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("assets/" + filename).nativePath;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, y,  App.core.stage.stageWidth,     viewHeight - y );
webView.loadURL( url);
```

Comment: Does iOS 11 still have access to applicationStorage?

Comment: What happens if you test `webView.loadURL()` by loading a PDF from online (HTTPS) server instead of loading local files into web browser?

Comment: I have the same problem and have tested to load a PDF from remote, which works. But not from the local system…

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, only a workaround: use Air version 25. [Since version 26 Adobe uses WKWebView instead of UIWebView](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_26_air_26_release_notes.html) and at least with their implementation this means local files can not be loaded. Luckily, apps compiled with AIR 25 run on iOS 11.
You can download older Air versions [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/la/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html).